# pandasで欠損により小数点がつく問題を回避したい

Tags: python, pandas

psycopg2でデータベースからSQLでデータを取得し、データフレーム化していますがその際欠損のあるbigint列がfloatになってしまいます。

Pandasで加工した後、DBに戻したいと考えているのですがfloatだとエラーが出てしまいます。

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint
```

整数値でも `.0` となっているのが原因のようです。
すべて文字列で読むなど試みましたが、DBからデータフレームにする時点で `.0` がついてきてしまいどうしようもないです。

どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.7

**追記**
データフレーム化するときに、`dtype=object`とすることで回避できました。
また、
`table.astype({'hoge': np.int64})`
とすると
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`
となってしまいます。

コメントで頂いたInt64についても試している段階です。
もう少しわかりましたら再度追記いたします。

Comment: 問題に関連するコードも質問文に含めると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: [Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194908)

Answer (score 1):

[欠損値NaNはfloat型](https://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2018/05/12/175309)として扱われます。
NaNを[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)で置換した上で[`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)でキャストする方法が手っ取り早いです。
なお単純に`astype`で置換すると `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` が発生します。
[本家の関連質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47013973)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'hoge' : [1, 2] })
print(df)
""" 
   hoge
1     1
2     2
""" 

df = df.reindex([0,1,2])
print(df)
""" 
   hoge
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   NaN
""" 

# df['hoge'] = df['hoge'].astype('int64')
# ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

df['hoge'] = df['hoge'].fillna(0).astype('int64') # fillnaで置換した値はDBに戻すタイミングで再加工すること
print(df)
""" 
   hoge
0     1
1     2
2     0
"""
```